# how to open a google map in a new window using my current map position

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I am using `php` and Google maps to create Google map.

```
    $map = $this->ci->gis->draw_map_position_by_lat_long($lat,$long);
    $this->ci->widgets['map']= $map;
```

function:

```
public function draw_map_position_by_lat_long($lat = NULL , $long = NULL) {

    $load['center'] = $lat . ',' . $long;
    $load['map_height'] = "191px";
    $this->ci->googlemaps->initialize($load);
    $i = 0;
    $marker = array();

    $marker['position'] = $lat . ',' . $long;
    $marker['draggable'] = 'TRUE';
    $marker['ondragend'] = "dragmarker(this.getPosition().lat(),this.getPosition().lng())";
    $this->ci->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);

    $map = $this->ci->googlemaps->create_map();
    $this->position_data = array('map' => $map);
    return $this->position_data;
}
```

I successfully created a google map like this:

[image]

When I click the map I want to open it on google map on another window,

in http://maps.google.com/

with a marker indicating my current position. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: I was reading on this page:
[PHP and Google Maps](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3.html) And that led me to this page: [Google Map Shortcode 2.0](http://web-argument.com/2011/05/04/google-map-shortcode-2-0-total-solution/) Which talks about opening the map in a new window.